# iOS: UITableViewCell reuse, image of button changing

Tags: ios, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I know this has been widely discussed before, and I'm sure, I'm just missing something simply, but like many others before me, I have an issue with cell reuse in a UITableView...
I have a button that displays an avatar, and I asynchronously download it the first time, and then cache it for later use...
When I scroll in my tableview while the images are being downloaded the first time, the avatars appear wrongfully in cells being reused, despite that I'm setting the avatar to a default avatar before beginning a download, so I'm hoping someone here will know the solution...

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
WaitingCell *waitingCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierWaiting];

if (waitingCell == nil) {
    waitingCell = [[WaitingCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierWaiting];
    waitingCell.delegate = self;
}

[waitingCell.userButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:DefaultAvatar] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[waitingCell.usernameLabel setText:username];
[waitingCell.scoreLabel setText:score];

__block UIImage *img;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    if([p1.objectId isEqualToString:currentUser.objectId])
    {
        img = [profileImages getProfileImageForUser:[p2 objectId]];
        waitingCell.user = p2;
    } else
    {
        img = [profileImages getProfileImageForUser:[p1 objectId]];
        waitingCell.user = p1;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [waitingCell.userButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    });
return waitingCell;
```

The image of "userButton" is the part that's getting reused until image is fully cached, but I thought that by setting it to a default value (DefaultAvatar is a constant file name), it would simply set the default avatar until the other was downloaded and it therefore wouldn't reuse other images..

The button is defined in my custom UITableViewCell called WaitingCell as such:

```
    self.userButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.userButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PlaceholderAvatar] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.userButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 8, 51, 54);
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.userButton];
```

Any ideas how I can keep it from reusing images and simply use the DefaultAvatar until the correct image is downloaded?

Comment: Did you set a break point or trace through this? Is `waitingCell` ever `nil` after `waitingCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: What is completedCell? Where and how do you define it?

Comment: rdelmar, ah my mistake, that was simply a C&P error, as I have another cell named that later, and I took the wrong C&P there - but it's correctly named waitingCell in my code :) also edited above code... Marcus, all the rows are nil when they are first encountered, but I'm beginning to sense that the problem might lie perhaps with my caching rather than the cell reuse, since the cells are nil when setting the temp image.. (if that makes any sense to you)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found another method than the one I'm currently using... The main problem was, that as I'm using the backend service Parse, I had to first download some other info, before I could get access to the file itself, which seemed to have caused some weird reuse of images, so I found a way to subclass UITableViewCell's in the API that seems to help...